# Updating jailbroken 6.0.1 ios to 7.1.1

Tags: jailbreak

What are the risks for updating ios apple device, which is already jailbroken ?

Answer (score -1):

You should **never** do this, as this will break your device and you will get in trouble restoring it. Please restore the device first so the jailbreak is removed.

You can jailbreak it afterwards again, as per [Evad3rs](http://www.evad3rs.net/search/label/Jailbreak%20iOS%207.1.1).